# Как убрать скролл браузера при открытии меню, а после закрытия обратно его включить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как убрать скролл браузера при открытии меню, а после его закрытия обратно его включить? Нашел вот такое решение, но не знаю как выключить это после того, как закроется меню:

```
document.onmousewheel = document.onwheel = function () {
  return false;
};
document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", function () {
  return false
}, false);
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode >= 33 && e.keyCode <= 40) return false;
};
return false;
```

[Вот ссылка на кодпен](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/LLrKpV?editors=0110)

P.S. overflow: hidden; не подходит, т.к. после отмены этого свойства будет скроллиться в самый верх страницы.

Comment: то-есть вы добавляете ивентлистенеры, а потом их надо удалить ? )

Comment: При `overflow: hidden` ничего наверх скроллиться не будет. Проверяй скрипты и ссылки с `href=#`.

Comment: Убирать скролл не надо, надо изначально класть два элемента, чтобы внешний перекрывал скролл.

Comment: откуда вы знаете, что не будет? попробуйте зайти на сайт с помощью айфона 5, где менюшка сделана подобным способом, и посмотрите что будет.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите определение нужно скроллить или нет во внешнюю переменную и в ваших ф-ях возвращайте ее:

```
 window.can_scroll = true;

 document.onmousewheel = document.onwheel = function () {
    return window.can_scroll;
 };
 document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", function () {
    return window.can_scroll
 }, false);
 document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 33 && e.keyCode <= 40) return window.can_scroll;
 };
```

Или удаляйте листенеры:

```
 // выключить скролл
 document.onmousewheel = document.onwheel = function () {
    return false;
 }; 
 function scrollOrNot() {
     return false;
 }
 document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", scrollOrNot, false);
 document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 33 && e.keyCode <= 40) return window.can_scroll;
 };

 // включить скролл
 document.onmousewheel = document.onwheel = function () {
    return true;
 }; 
 document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    return true;
 };
 document.removeEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", scrollOrNot, false);
```

Comment: хм, работает. Но как сделать, чтобы внутри менюшки можно было скроллить?

Comment: Тогда вам нужен 1 описанный мной вариант.

Каждая из этих ф-й принимает аргумент event, у него в свою очередь есть св-во target, соответственно проверяйте event.target и если он равен вашим "менюшкам" - разрешайте скроллить, в остальных случаях - возвращайте window.can_scroll